# How to prevent pushes to heroku when not logged in

Tags: git, heroku, push, heroku-toolbelt

I use a semi-public computer and would like to be able to logout (maybe with some setting) and then not be able to push. When I log out, I get the "Local credentials cleared." message and while I can't see my logs while logged out, I can push. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging out will only affect any interaction with Heroku via the command line - to prevent access via pushes you would have to delete your ssh key from the ~/.ssh folder.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try just removing it from my heroku account when I want to log out and the adding back.